# Correct Way To Draw Unmanaged Bitmap To Screen

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, bitmap, uwp

I am busy working on creating a xaml view for drawing a bitmap from unmanaged code to the screen - using a `Canvas` background `Brush`. There are several things that I am unsure about (especially since the docs are minimal/missing).

I am using SkiaSharp to do the drawing, so the memory block must be accessible in unmanaged memory - and I want to avoid copying back and forth.

I have found a few ways to do this, but I am not sure about the workings of the framework to know if I have done this right. The first way is using a `byte[]` and a `WriteableBitmap`:

```
int width, height, length = ...;

// create the bits (once off)
byte[] pixels = new byte[length];
GCHandle buff = GCHandle.Alloc(pixels, GCHandleType.Pinned);
WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
this.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = bitmap };

// draw (in a game loop)
DrawUsingSkiaSharp(buff.AddrOfPinnedObject());

// update the UI
var stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
stream.Write(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
bitmap.Invalidate();
```

This works fine, and I am only copying "once" per frame. Also, I can draw to the same image, and the bitmap acting as a double buffer. But, is the `bitmap.Invalidate` resulting in a second copy to the screen?

I found that I can use `SoftwareBitmap` too:

```
// create
SoftwareBitmap bitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(
    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, 
    width, height, 
    BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);

// draw
using (var buffer = bitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.ReadWrite))
using (var bufferRef = buffer.CreateReference())
{
    byte* b;
    uint capacity;
    ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)bufferRef).GetBuffer(out b, out capacity);
    DrawUsingSkiaSharp(b);
}

// update
var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
this.Background = new ImageBrush { };
var action = source.SetBitmapAsync(bitmap);
action.Completed = (asyncInfo, asyncStatus) {
    ((ImageBrush)this.Background).ImageSource = source;
};
```

But once I have assigned the bitmap to the brush, I cannot draw on it again (LockBuffer throws). A way around this is to have a second bitmap and copy to that. But is this an improvement over `WriteableBitmap` - especially I now have to deal with the async complexities? What does `SetBitmapAsync` really do and why is it async? Can't the source just read it - or is there a copy here too?

Is there a third and better way, should I use one or the other, or is there a different way to do this? Like not using a brush and drawing directly to the `Canvas` (or is there a better control)

Also, what is the correct way to use `SoftwareBitmap` and `SoftwareBitmapSource` when drawing using a game loop?

So many options, and no documentation! :)

Comment: Although the document is lacking for this nuget package, you still can do some research for some questions for example, why a method is async, try to google it. Have you already checked the example of `SkiaSharp`? Did you develop a uwp app? Since your questions are too many and do not have a center topic so it may spent more time to reply to you.